# Django REST framework serializer is slow even with prefetch related

Tags: django, performance, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize 30-50 instances with a few nested models each (e.g. Posts with some data, nested image and nested writer details).

The serialization takes 50-150ms and makes the response quite slow. The data is prefetched so the queries themselves take around 15ms.

What's the best approach to speed up the serialization?

Comment: i think problem is not in serializers. Respone is slow because rest framework needs to render not only your response(hi is rendering filters and another gui).
Try to make your request like this `http://localhost:8000/api/whatever-list.json` . It must be more faster

Comment: I measured only the call to `Serializer(objects, many=True).data`. The entire request is even slower.

Comment: did you solve this? Im facing a similar problem

Comment: No, I gave up on fixing Django and instead I cached the serialized response. The first response is slow but the rest of them are way faster. I also cached partial responses for user-dependent requests